# Continuous crawl cannot be enabled because the disable operation is in progress. Retry to enable it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

We are cannot crawl a content source, when we try to enable continous crawl we get the following error message:

**Continuous crawl cannot be enabled because the disable operation is in progress. Retry to enable it.**

[image]

Also, we are not do any type of crawl: Full or Incremental, when we try to do so it stops immediately. I did not see any error in the event logs.

In ULS log I see the following error:

> 10/05/2015 06:08:53.76     w3wp.exe (SERVER3554:0x091C)
>     0x16F0  SharePoint Foundation           General
>     ajlz0   High    Getting Error Message for Exception
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   Continuous crawl cannot be enabled because the disable operation is in
>   progress. Retry to enable it.   (Fault Detail is equal to An
>   ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Continuous crawl cannot
>   be enabled because the disable operation is in progress. Retry to
>   enable it.      at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApi.WriteAndReturnVersion(CodeToRun`1
>   remoteCode, VoidCodeToRun localCode, Int32 versionIn)     at
>   SyncInvokeEditContentSource(Object , Object[] , Object[] )     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs,
>   Object[]...   46a1349d-ab3f-f046-8084-5fa5b33646d

9

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what happened, but I deleted the content source and created a new one and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a few minutes and then edit your content source to enable Continue Crawl. You cannot change the content source setting while it is still updating the content source. You shouldn't delete/recreate your content source.